# Variable is not updating - func takes default variable

Tags: swift, swift5

In my `ThirdScreenViewController` I change the variable `number` with the `IBAction pressed`.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ThirdScreenViewController: UIViewController {

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

        }
     var weatherManager = WeatherManager()
    var team = "leer"
    static var number = 1
    
    @IBAction func bayernMunchen(_ sender: UIButton) {
        team = "bayernMunchen"
    }
    @IBAction func borussiaDortmund(_ sender: UIButton) {
        team = "borussiaDortmund"
    }
    @IBAction func schalke(_ sender: UIButton) {
        team = "schalke"
    }
    @IBAction func pressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        switch team {
        case "bayernMunchen":
        ThirdScreenViewController.number = 46
        case "borussiaDortmund":
        ThirdScreenViewController.number = 41
        case "schalke":
        ThirdScreenViewController.number = 45
        default: print(8)
        }
        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
        let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WeatherViewController") as! WeatherViewController
        self.present(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)

    }
}
```

In an other swift (not a View Controller) file I have a function which takes `number` and does something with it.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

var TeamOne = ""
var TeamTwo = ""
var ScoreOne = ""
var ScoreTwo = ""

var TeamThree = ""
var TeamFour = ""
var ScoreThree = ""
var ScoreFour = ""
var cityName = ThirdScreenViewController.number

struct WeatherManager {
    
    
    let weatherURL = "https://livescore-api.com/api-client/teams/matches.json?number=10&team_id=19&key=d33FTnnd6qwvEmjz&secret=BbO3REPYFXvb7fpkit0cQnpXNWssiL1U&number=3&team_id=\(cityName)"
    
    func fetchWeather () {
        let urlString = "\(weatherURL)"
        perfromRequest(urlString: urlString)
        
    }
    
    func perfromRequest(urlString: String)
    {
        //1.Url erstellen
        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            //2. URLSession starten
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            //3. Give session a task
            let task =  session.dataTask(with: url) { (gettingInfo, response, error) in
                if error != nil{
                    print(error!)
                    return
                }
                
                if let safeFile = gettingInfo {
                    self.parseJSON(weatherFile: safeFile)
                }
            }
            //4. Start the task
            task.resume()
            
        }
    }
    
    //Das Ergebnis von oben wird hier ausgegeben
    func parseJSON(weatherFile: Data) {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do{
            let decodedFile =  try decoder.decode(WeatherFile.self, from: weatherFile)
            TeamOne = decodedFile.data[0].home_name
            ScoreOne = decodedFile.data[0].score
            
            TeamTwo = decodedFile.data[0].away_name
            ScoreTwo = decodedFile.data[0].score
            
            TeamThree = decodedFile.data[1].home_name
            ScoreThree = decodedFile.data[1].score
            
            TeamFour = decodedFile.data[1].away_name
            ScoreFour = decodedFile.data[1].score
          
            
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
   
}
```

In a third swift file I use this func `weatherManager.fetchWeather()` to call what happens in my second swift file.
But here is the problem. It takes the variable `number` with the default value 1 and not with the value 41/46/45. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically global variables outside of any class and static variables to share data is bad practice.

Apart from that to get the team ID dynamically delete the line

```
var cityName = ThirdScreenViewController.number
```

In the struct replace

```
let weatherURL = "https://livescore-api.com/api-client/teams/matches.json?number=10&team_id=19&key=d33FTnnd6qwvEmjz&secret=BbO3REPYFXvb7fpkit0cQnpXNWssiL1U&number=3&team_id=\(cityName)"
```

with

```
let weatherURL = "https://livescore-api.com/api-client/teams/matches.json?number=10&team_id=19&key=d33FTnnd6qwvEmjz&secret=BbO3REPYFXvb7fpkit0cQnpXNWssiL1U&number=3&team_id="
```

and

```
let urlString = "\(weatherURL)"
```

with

```
let urlString = weatherURL + String(ThirdScreenViewController.number)
```

Note: Consider to rename the **weather** related stuff to the **team** related stuff

Comment: Thank you it worked. If I may ask. Why did my code not work? It is because of the variable cityName that I used? I guess I should use ThirdScreenViewController.number directly? And you said I shouldn't do it like that. Can you name an alternative?

Comment: Because `cityName` is initialized when the enclosing Swift file is created and it's not updated when the static value changes. You should always encapsulate data in structs or enums.